# How to remove event emittes with mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, eventemitter

I get the following warning when I run test which connect and disconnect heavily to the database.

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connected listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

I assume that the emmiters are not removed after a disconnect.

I found a solution for my tests. Since I really fully disconnect I can do a

```
mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners();
```

In all other cases I would go for mongoose.connection.removeListeners('event', cb); I am unclear what to do in the callback.

Comment: Probably you can find your answer here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1992

Answer (score 0):

Removing all listeners did the trick for me:

```
mongoose.connection.removeAllListeners()
```